# Can't set name to my Model to be Roles in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, models

When naming my model to be Roles.php laravel don't loaded it?
Just for test I set some name and everything was fine. Is that word saved by Laravel for some reason or I have something very messed up :)?

Comment: What exactly to do you mean by "Laravel doesn't load it"? It isn't autoloaded? Did you try to `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: You might want to read up on autoloading PSR-0 to PSR-4. Your defined class XXX should be reflected in the autoloading, normally your file is named identically.

Comment: Hi, I mean that can't access any method in this Model. The error is "Call to undefined method ". I tried to do composer dump-autoload but I get the same massage.. Only rename to Role and everything works like a charm.

Comment: How do you call these functions? can you show us some code?

Comment: Of course, just call it in controller for example $allRoles = Roles::whereNull('deleted_at')->get();
The Eloquent is extended in model class.

Comment: should be named Role not Roles